# Population Database in C#... Program not running but theres no errors

Tags: c#

I've written all the code and there's no errors except for when I go to run it, it says this:

"Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'C:\Users\Smith\source\repos\Population_Database\Population_Database\bin\Debug\Population_Database.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly."

**The textbook says this:**

In the Chap11 folder of the Sample Programs, you will find a database file
named PopulationDB.mdf. The database has a table named City. The City table
has the following columns:
Column Name Data Type
City nvarchar(50) Primary key
Population float
The City column stores the name of a city and the Population column stores the
population of that city. The database has 20 rows already entered.
Create an application that connects to the PopulationDB.mdf database and allows
the user to perform the following:
• Use data-bound controls to add new rows to the database, change existing
rows, and delete rows.
• Sort the list of cities by population, in ascending order.
• Sort the list of cities by population, in descending order.
• Sort the list of cities by name.
• Get the total population of all the cities.
• Get the average population of all the cities.
• Get the highest population.
• Get the lowest population.

**Here is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Population_Database
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void newrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from City", cn);
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("City");
        adapter.Fill(ds, "City");
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["City"].NewRow();
        row["City"] = textBox1.Text;
        row["Population"] = textBox2.Text;
        ds.Tables["City"].Rows.Add(row);
        adapter.Update(ds, "Income");
        cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Details Entered Sucessfully ....");
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from City ORDER BY Population ASC", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            String tot;
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = tot.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from City ORDER BY Population DESC", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            String tot;
            comboBox2.SelectedItem = tot.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select City from City ", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            String tot;
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = tot.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM(Population) from City", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            double tot;
            tot = Convert.ToDouble(sdr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
            textBox3.Text = tot.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select AVG(Population) from City", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            double tot;
            tot = Convert.ToDouble(sdr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
            textBox4.Text = tot.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select MAX(Population) from City", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            double tot;
            tot = Convert.ToDouble(sdr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
            textBox5.Text = tot.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PopulationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select MIN(Population) from City", cn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            double tot;
            tot = Convert.ToDouble(sdr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
            textBox6.Text = tot.ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So _none_ of that code relates to the error, if such compiles as claimed. Take time to _read_ and _search for_ error messages. The searchable message is “Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing”. Give it a go (ie. google).

Comment: What is the error mean then

Comment: Go to the build menu and select clean, then rebuild. Does that solve the problem? Does that yield a different error? *I'm assuming visual studio.*

Comment: @theraot yes actually... now that i did that it says "Use of unassigned local variable 'tot' "

Comment: @razer3021 makes sense, searching `tot` in your code it appears you declare it and then use it right away, without giving it any value.

Answer (score 0):

Taking ahead from comments:
You text boxes won’t display any value because you are not assigning tot to anything in your string tot lines, just declaring.

Tot = sdr.item[whatever column name you want to display value of] will solve you unassigned issue.